# How to store a list of values in Postman and then pass a random value from the list in a API call?

Tags: postman, postman-pre-request-script

I am new to Postman. I have dabbled with automating some of my API calls here in I set counters and randomize characters. However, I need to store a list of values (for this exercise it could be 1000 individual values) and then randomize which value is being used in the API call.

For example, storing a list of 1000 US Cities. For this example, lets use the three below.

San Diego,
San Francisco,
Louisville

Then when I make the API call via POST, I send a random value (e.g. a city) from the list of 1000 cities. How can this be achieved in Postman?

Comment: What did you already try? Please share your code. Thanks for considering [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a pre-request script in your collection. That way your list of cites/items will be available for all the requests in your collection.

1. Select your collection in Postman
2. Go to the **Pre-request Script** tab (these scripts will run before every request in the collection, so you will get a random value each time)
3. Add code to select a random value and assign it to a variable, example below

```js
//Available Items
var itemsAvailable = 
[
    "Item1",
    "Item2",
    "Item3"
];

//Pick an Item
var item = _.sample(itemsAvailable);

//Log it to console for debugging
console.log("Item Picked: " + item);

//Set our variable so it can be used in requests via {{MyVariable}}
pm.environment.set("MyVariable", item);
```

4. Now update your request and use the variable `{{MyVariable}}` which will contain a random value from the list defined above.

The `{{MyVariable}}` may not show up in the intellisense until you execute at least one request with the pre-request script and the variable gets added to the environment. This script will also output to the console the value that was chosen to assist in debugging.

Answer (score 1):

```
_.sample(['January', 'February', 'March'])
```

create a list of 1000 items and use lodash sample function to select random element from it

Answer (score 1):

Add all the values of the cities in an array, then use the below code snipped to randomly select one of the city

```js
var cities = ["San Francisco", "San Diego", "Boston"];
pm.environment.set("CITY", cities[Math.floor(Math.random() * cities.length)]);
```

Edit the Body of your **POST** request to pass the **CITY** variable

```json
{
  "city":"{{CITY}}"
}
```

Comment: There's a way to have different values? Using this solution, if a made a request with two items, it'll have the same value.

`[ {"city":"{{CITY}}"}, {"city":"{{CITY}}"}]`

will produce...

`[ {"city":"Boston"}, {"city":"Boston"}]`